# Unit test with Jasmine and Angular 13 -> Unable to query a DOM modal element created with MDBootstrap 5

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mdbootstrap

I would like to unit test if a modal is opened when I click a button. The modal was created with MDBootstrap v5 for Angular 13.

The issue I am trying to understand is why the const modal (see test below) is null, so my last assertion fails. I think there is something to do with the tsconfig.spec.json, since I am not sure what files from MDB I should include there. Really appreciate any input on this.

This is the test:

```
it(`should open a dialog when the button 'Add a Store' is clicked`, fakeAsync(() => {

    const button: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.ms-auto');

    button.click();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    flush();

    const modal: HTMLElement =
      fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.modal-content')!;

    expect(fakeDialogService.open).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    expect(modal).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

This is the tsconfig.spec.json:

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": ["jasmine"]
  },
  "files": ["src/test.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

This is my .ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MdbModalRef, MdbModalService } from 'mdb-angular-ui-kit/modal';
import { MdbTableDirective } from 'mdb-angular-ui-kit/table';
import { GlobalProgressbarService } from '../../shared/components/linear-progress-bar/linear-progress-bar.service';
import { NavbarService } from '../../shared/components/navbar/navbar.service';
import { IFirestoreStore, IStore } from '../../shared/models/store.model';
import { StoreService } from '../../shared/services/store.service';
import { UserService } from '../../shared/services/user.service';
import { DialogCreateStoreComponent } from './components/dialog-create-store/dialog-create-store.component';

interface IStoreElement extends IStore {
  products: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-store-list-page',
  templateUrl: './store-list-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./store-list-page.component.scss'],
})
export class StoreListPageComponent implements OnInit {
  stores: IStoreElement[] = [];

  @ViewChild('table') table!: MdbTableDirective<IStore>;

  columns: string[] = [
    'Name',
    'Address',
    'Region',
    'Last Visit',
    'Products',
    ' ',
  ];

  searchTerm = '';

  isLoading!: boolean;

  modalRef: MdbModalRef<DialogCreateStoreComponent> | null = null;

  constructor(
    private user: UserService,
    private STORE_API: StoreService,
    private navbar: NavbarService,
    private loader: GlobalProgressbarService,
    private router: Router,
    private dialog: MdbModalService
  ) {
    this.navbar.showAllNavbar();
    this.loader.show();
    this.isLoading = true;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    (async () => {
      if (!this.user.companyProjectId) {
        this.loader.hide();
        return;
      }

      const stores = await this.STORE_API.getStoresByCompanyProjectId(
        this.user.companyProjectId
      );

      const storesArr = await this.handleStoresWithFullData(stores);

      this.setStores(storesArr);
      this.loader.hide();
      this.isLoading = false;
    })();
  }

  onClickItem = (storeId: string) => {
    this.router.navigate([`/stores/${storeId}`]);
  };

  getStores = () => this.stores;

  setStores = (stores: IStore[]) => {
    this.stores = stores.map((s) => {
      return {
        ...s,
        products: s.products_counter,
      };
    });
  };

  async handleStoresWithFullData(stores: IFirestoreStore[]): Promise<IStore[]> {
    return await Promise.all(
      stores.map((store) => this.STORE_API.getStoreWithVisit(store))
    );
  }

  search(event: Event): void {
    if (!event) return;

    this.searchTerm = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value
      .toLowerCase()
      .trim();
    this.table.search(this.searchTerm);
  }

  clearInputSearchbar(event: any) {
    if (event.target.value) {
      return;
    }

    this.searchTerm = '';
    this.table.search(this.searchTerm);
  }

  openStoreDialog = () => {
    this.modalRef = this.dialog.open(DialogCreateStoreComponent, {
      modalClass: 'modal-dialog-centered',
      ignoreBackdropClick: true,
    });
  };
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column px-5 py-5">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
    <h1>Stores</h1>
    <app-button-primary
      class="ms-auto"
      type="filled"
      (click)="openStoreDialog()"
    >
      Add a Store
    </app-button-primary>
  </div>

  <div
    class="d-flex w-100 align-items-start justify-content-start gap-5 px-2 py-3"
  >
    <mdb-form-control class="mt-2 w-50">
      <div class="input-group border rounded">
        <span class="input-group-text border-0" id="basic-addon1"
          ><i class="fas fa-search"></i
        ></span>

        <input
          mdbInput
          type="search"
          class="form-control rounded border-0"
          placeholder="Ex. Giant Food."
          aria-label="Ex. Giant Food."
          aria-describedby="search-addon"
          id="search-input"
          (keyup)="search($event)"
          (search)="this.clearInputSearchbar($event)"
        />
      </div>
    </mdb-form-control>
  </div>
  <div class="datatable flex-fill d-flex w-100 mt-2">
    <table
      mdbTable
      mdbTableSort
      #table="mdbTable"
      #sort="mdbTableSort"
      [sort]="sort"
      [dataSource]="this.stores"
      class="table datatable-table"
    >
      <thead class="datatable-header">
        <tr>
          <th
            *ngFor="let header of columns"
            [mdbTableSortHeader]="header"
            scope="col"
            class="table-header"
          >
            {{ header | titlecase }}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody
        class="datatable-body"
        *ngIf="table.data?.length! >= 1; else noMatches"
        id="storeTableBody"
      >
        <tr
          *ngFor="let data of table.data"
          scope="row"
          (click)="this.onClickItem(data.fkey)"
          class="clickable"
        >
          <td>
            {{ data.name }}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{ data.address }}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{ data.region }}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{ data.lastVisit | date: "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm a" }}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{ data.products }}
            {{ data.products > 1 ? "products" : "product" }}
          </td>
          <td><i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical"></i></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<ng-template #noMatches>
  <table *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <i>No matching results found</i>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that we don't know where `MDBootstrap5` will paint the modal, it's not in your component's HTML so the following line will fail:

```
 const modal: HTMLElement =
      fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.modal-content')!;
```

For me, this test is good enough:

```
it(`should open a dialog when the button 'Add a Store' is clicked`, fakeAsync(() => {

    const button: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.ms-auto');

    button.click();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    flush();

    expect(fakeDialogService.open).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  }));
```

If you really want to test for the presence of the modal, you can try:

```
import { MdbModalModule } from 'mdb-angular-ui-kit/modal';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  // !! make sure you have MdbModalModule in imports
  imports: [MdbModalModule]
}).compileComponents();

it(`should open a dialog when the button 'Add a Store' is clicked`, fakeAsync(() => {

    const button: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.ms-auto');

    button.click();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    flush();
    
    // !! use document.querySelector since the modal will be somewhere in the DOM and not in the component's HTML
    const modal: HTMLElement = document.querySelector('.modal-content');

    expect(fakeDialogService.open).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    expect(modal).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, but unfortunately it did not work on my side (the modal presence test I mean). The Mdb support told me that it was possible for them to query the modal as above, my I really cannot figure out why it does not pass on my side :(